# Ignore javascript error in HTML file (VS Code)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have an HTML file which is a Django template.  For the most part, it's pretty boring, there's a bit of HTML and some Javascript code inside script tags.

The problem is that I've inserted a single line of Django template language (with the double curly braces), and it cascades into a thousand different errors on every line.  How do I ignore this?  All I can find is `// @ts-ignore` on Google which doesn't seem to work with HTML files.

I don't even know where to begin.  Is this a linting issue?  What linter am I using, which documentation should I look at, etc.  I assume I should be using the default tools for javascript.  Please help!

The line in question is:

```
var achievementFlag = {{ achievement_flag|yesno:"true,false" }};
```

Naturally, the double curly braces is bad, as is the | and the :.  And now the javascript just has squiggles all over it.

Comment: Have you tried setting the language mode for the file in VS Code? Near the bottom right of the screen is the selected language. If you click on that, you can change the language. If Django template is not available, change the language to html (twig) - seems to be pretty close. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file

Comment: The extensions for Django templates take away more features than they add in, so it hasn't been all that helpful.  I was really hoping there'd be a simple way to ignore a line.  Currently I'm just commenting it out while I work on the rest of the code, but that's not a great way to tackle it in the long run.

Comment: Try the html(twig) extension. It doesn't take away much - it may not match Django 100%, but I believe you will be able to keep the js in the file

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, but initially one of the Twig extensions was pretty horrible, but Twig Language 2 by mblode is fantastic and is now working as I'd like.  Wasn't the solution I expected, but thanks a ton!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to settings.json

```
"html.validate.scripts": false,
```

this line will make vscode ignores javascript validation in HTML files

credits: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17433#issuecomment-273870328

Comment: Is there any way only work for django template validation  not all js code?

Comment: ok, I see django template extension solving this issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround I usually use is to use JSON.parse:

```
var achievementFlag = JSON.parse('{{ achievement_flag|yesno:"true,false" }}');
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` will throw an error with the value that you are passing (`{{ achievement_flag|yesno:"true,false" }}`)

Comment: The expression inside double curly braces will be replaced by Django by an actual "true" or "false" value.